# Configuring a virtual key hotkey in TS3?

Tags: teamspeak

## Information

Alright, so I play a game called *ArmA 3* a lot. I usually play on Roleplaying servers, and they use a plugin called *Task Force Radio.*
*Task Force Radio* (From now on abbreviated to **TFR**) is  a plugin that uses *Teamspeak 3* and it's 3D sound environment features to work.
Basically, if someone in-game is too far away from me to hear, the in-game mod will tell the *TFR* plugin that, and it will mute them, if they are far away but within earshot, *TFR* will turn down the volume for them accordingly. If they are to my left, TFR will make them sound like they
're to the left. If you're still confused about that [check out this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQAYIXx7wlg)
**TL;DR** I use *Teamspeak3* to communicate with people in-game.

I also have a plugin for Teamspeak3 called *soundboard*. Take a guess as to what it is.
*Ding.* It's a soundboard. It lets me play songs and sounds through my microphone on Teamspeak, and when used with *Task Force Radio*, it allows me to do some cool stuff.

I have a Logitech G910 for a keyboard, and on the side of it is *9 macro keys.* I have these keys set to emulate **F13-F21** function keys.

### So, what's the problem?

I mentioned I have function keys **F13-F21**, well the reason I have those is because in *TeamSpeak* I want to bind those keys to soundboard keys.
So say for example someone makes a terrible joke, and no one laughs. I want to be able to seize the opportunity to quickly hit **F13** and play a 90's laugh track, so he can feel ever worse about himself.

### Well, then why don't you just bind Laugh Track for F13, you big dummy?

For some reason, TeamSpeak3 doesn't properly register **F13** when assigning it to a hotkey. Instead, it just replaces it with *124,* the virtual key for **F13**.
[image]
[image]
**Left:** Trying to bind F12
**Right:** Trying to bind F13

### Okay, then what?

Well, I went hunting through the TS3 directory. And found the text data in the *settings.db* that directly relates to the hotkeys.
[image]
Now I'm stuck. I've tried replacing the *Keyboard124* and the *124* string after it with *KeyboardF13* and *F13*, but that just causes teamspeak to create a new settings file.

So my question, how would I modify this data to allow me to use F13 as a hotkey in TS3?

Comment: If teamspeak doesn't respond well to virtual keys, you could test using the scan codes mentioned in that other post. send, {sc64} would be F13.

Comment: It looks like the  .db file is not plain text, so editing it in a text editor and saving may corrupt the non text data, leading to teamspeak not liking it. Do you have something that can open and save database files properly? You could try Excel or Access. If teamspeak use their own database format, it may be difficult to edit it.